# Visual Studio Load Test - Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, windows-authentication, load-testing

We are using Visual Studio 2013 to perform a load test against a desktop application that communicates to the backend via TCP.

It uses windows authentication, whereby it takes the context of the user currently logged onto the machine, and uses this to log the user into the application automatically when invoked.

We are having trouble figuring out how to add more users to the test since we cannot get past the windows authentication.

Has anyone encountered this before? If yes, what was your work around?

There are articles about adding data sources to the run settings, but that is for a web test context. There isn't an option to add a data source when the project is set to a load test context.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A Visual Studio Load Test is a mechanism for managing multiple executions of test cases. Load tests are very good at managing Web Performance Tests, but they can run several other types of test. Your question does not specify what sort of test cases the load test is calling.

Assuming that the test calls Web Performance Tests (in `*.webtest` files) then the web test itself can be data driven and that data can include the user name and password needed for Windows Authentication; use the "Set credentials" command in the Web Test Editor (the command icon looks like a padlock).

If you have a Coded Web Performance Test then I suggest recording a minimal `.webtest`, setting the credentials on that, converting it to a coded web test and then copying the relevant code into your test.

There are no facilities to add a data source to a load test. That is because load tests manage other test cases, but are not test cases themselves.